# How to install kernel 4.4 on debian testing?

Tags: debian, kernel

Hello can someone tell me how to install kernel 4.4 on current debian testing ? I have a bug that might be solved by the kernel 4.4 so I want to give it a shot but can't find the name of the package to install it.

Comment: `apt-cache search '^linux-image-.*-amd64'` can come in handy, in addition to Stephen's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're looking for the `amd64` kernel, the package is [`linux-image-4.4.0-1-amd64`](https://packages.debian.org/source/testing/linux).

Comment: terrific you're a real life savior, thanks